# any way to get offline access token w/o verification via credit card or phone?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I want to be able to occasionally programmatically grab some data from the graph API using python that is already accessible to my own FB account.  Almost all of what I want is public, so is easy, but a couple Pages, although for large-scale brands, happen to be restricted to logged in users.  These are accessible when using an access token (including the example one on the doc page).

I've read that what I need for this is an offline access token so that it won't expire.  However, in trying to go through creating one, by first creating an app, it's now asking for credit card or phone verification.

Is there any (allowed) way to get an offline access token without this step?  I don't even want to create an app in the first place.  I just need a token to pass in with my https://graph.facebook.com/PAGENAME? queries.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, as far as I know. The verification part is needed for you to access the developer tools and without them you cannot create a new app (the first solution) or use the Graph Explorer to generate an offline_access token.

You could make someone who has a verified account an admin to your pages and then use his access_token, but you would have to keep him as a permanent admin for the token to keep working, so I don't really think you would want that.

Just verify your account. Mine went really smoothly, they simply sent me an sms, no charges for me to pay, I entered the code and that was it

Comment: Can I borrow your phone, then? :) My credit-card verification is anything but smooth, so far. :(